# how to call the posts of a different custom taxonomy of a category name in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I have written a code for displaying all the posts of a particular category from a particular custom taxonomy. Here `$term` is the name of the category of which the posts are to be displayed. The following code is being given below :

```
<?php 

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => '-1',
        'post_type'      => 'brand',
        'taxonomy'       => 'brand-category',
        'terms'          => $term,
        'category_name'  => $term,
        'order'          => 'DESC'
    );

    $results = new wp_Query($args);

    if(have_posts()){
        while($results->have_posts()){
            $results->the_post();
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'large');
    ?>
    <div class="item">
        <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" alt="pvc hose"> 
    </div>
    <?php }
    }

?>
```

The above code is not displaying the images which I have given in the particular category in the particular taxonomy brand-category. Can anyone suggest corrections to this code?

Comment: How did you add images to your category? Or do you mean images from each post in the category? First you can check if your query returns anything by putting `print_r($results);` after the `WP_Query()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For custom taxonomies you should use the `tax_query`parameter. Your args should be like:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type'      => 'brand',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',    
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'brand-category',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $term,
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'brand-category',
            'field'    => 'name',
            'terms'    => $term,
        ),
    ),
);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: this code is working but i want to display only the posts of a particular category slug name  which i have stored in $term. now its displaying all the posts for every category name or slug. in this code how to give the category name or slug ? i have included the category name or slug name but the posts are not displaying.

Comment: @anna, I think I've misunderstood your necessity. I've edited the code to solve your problem, hope it helps.